# Visual Studio 2013 Extremely Slow at Saving Files

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have a WPF project where it sometimes takes extremely long time to save a module.
(I see the little saving floppy pulsating "forever" and nothing happens for several minutes).

Often I have to use the Task Manager to end Visual Studio and then start over again.
The first couple of times after restart, saving is pretty quick, but then it takes forever again.

Any hints to solve this problem would be very much appreciated.

---

**Problem fixed** in Tools->Options->Source Control, by setting the source control plug-in to "None", which is fine as we are not using TFS or Git for the project. Not sure why this works, but Visual Studio does not "hang" after this change.

[image]

Comment: This is an environmental problem of course, you cannot get an answer when you don't describe it.  Start by disabling anti-malware, next are add-ins.

Comment: My Visual Studio is also slow when saving XAML files, but I *am* using SCM, so your fix won't work for me.

Comment: Didn't help. There is should be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you can follow to increase the performance

1. Go to a xaml file via solution explorer. Right click open with..Choose Source Code (Text) Editor and Set as default.
   [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLsFw.png)
2. Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML > Miscellaneous and check the check box "Always open documents in full XAML view".
   [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfoET.png)